# Multiple sliders on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Ok, I builded a slider in javascript and Jquery (with help of you guys) But now I want to have multiple sliders on 1 page. While using just one javascript. BUT...the slider can be different in width (or number of items): also the name of the slider is different because of the css width.

So How do I use 1 javascript to controle different sliders

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#temp{
height: 300px;
}

#container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#CDFAA8;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left: 13px;
    }

#slider{
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#063;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

#block1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#067;
    float: left;
}

#block2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background:#079;
    float: left;
}

#move_right{
    height: 150px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    z-index: 200;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

#move_left{
    height: 150px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 200;
    opacity: 0.2;
}​
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="temp">
<div id="container">
    <div id="move_left"><button id="right">&laquo;</button></div><div id="move_right"><br><br><button id="left">&raquo;</button></div>
<div id="slider">

    <div id="block1">1</div>    
    <div id="block2">2</div>
    <div id="block1">3</div>    
    <div id="block2">4</div> 
    <div id="block1">5</div>    
    <div id="block2">6</div>
    <div id="block1">7</div>    
    <div id="block2">8</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="slider">

    <div id="block1">1</div>    
    <div id="block2">2</div>
    <div id="block1">3</div>    
    <div id="block2">4</div> 
    <div id="block1">5</div>    
    <div id="block2">6</div>
    <div id="block1">7</div>    
    <div id="block2">8</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function($) {
    var slider = $('#slider'),
        step = 500,
        left = parseInt(slider.css('left'), 10),
        max = $('#container').width() - slider.width(),
        min = 0;

    $("#left").click(function() {
        if (left > max) {
            var newLeft = left - step;
            left = (newLeft>max) ? newLeft : max;
            $("#slider").animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });

    $("#right").click(function() {
        if (left < 0) {
            var newLeft = left + step;
            left = (newLeft<min) ? newLeft : min;
            slider.animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: try a second one with `<div id="slider2">` and
 `var slider2 = $('#slider2')`  and rename the slider in "right"  as slider2  maybe that helps?

Comment: IDs must be unique, you can't have multiple elements with the same id. Also, JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: Have you investigated the jQuery UI slider? http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#multiple-vertical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fine:

```
(function($) {
    $('#temp #container').each(function(){
        var slider = $(this).find('#slider'),
        parent = $(this),
        step = 500,
        left = parseInt(slider.css('left'), 10),
        max = parent.width() - slider.width(),
        min = 0;

    parent.find("#left").click(function() {
        if (left > max) {
            var newLeft = left - step;
            left = (newLeft>max) ? newLeft : max;
            slider.animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });

    parent.find("#right").click(function() {
        if (left < 0) {
            var newLeft = left + step;
            left = (newLeft<min) ? newLeft : min;
            slider.animate({
                "left": left + 'px'
            }, "slow");
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/Nn4Kz/)

Comment: the proposed solution's jfiddle has multiple ID's of the same name, and it doesn't work. The main issue with this thing is to not have to use ID's, so that one piece of code can apply to all sliders on the page independently. Therein is the rub, as they say.

Comment: @Charlie observed, "the jfiddle has multiple ID's of the same name, and it doesn't work. The main issue with this thing is to not have to use ID's, so that one piece of code can apply to all sliders on the page independently. Therein is the rub, as they say."

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could do some code which can take a selector to a wrapper element (which has the required slider elements inside) as some parameter. And then you can from this element create selectors which are more dynamic. I'm not sure where you get "step = 500" from, but that's maybe something you could grab dynamically from some relevant element.

Comment: thanks! I was trying to work build a work arround in PHP so I could fill in different variables per script. but than I would have like 10 similar scripts running at the same time...