# How to get multiple slider on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get a working onepage site with multiple sliders. But after more than 2 slider its not working anymore. How to fix it?

I've got the code from w3schools for multiple sliders (trying to build up a website with w3.css framework).
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

I tried to copy from 2 to 6 sliders and changed the "var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"] " to my 6 defined. But its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Multiple Slider</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/side-menu.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides4" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides4" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides4" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides4" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides5" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides5" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides5" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides5" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides6" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides6" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides6" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides6" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = [1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1","mySlides2","mySlides3","mySlides4","mySlides5","mySlides6"]
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);

function plusDivs(n, no) {
  showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showDivs(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect a working output and be confused why its not working.

Comment: maybe your ask is duplicate. Check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658840/multiple-sliders-on-one-page

Comment: Try to use different class for each slider for example: 

w3-display-container-1
w3-display-container-2
w3-display-containe-3

Comment: @CuongHoang but what of extra declaration i need then for css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are passing wrong index in every slider,

```
plusDivs(-1, 0) //this is for first
```

you are doing same for all other sliders, instead you should do this.

```
plusDivs(-1, 0) //first

plusDivs(-1, 1) //second

plusDivs(-1, 2) //third
```

This way you will have your slider working.

```js
var slideIndex = [1, 1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);

function plusDivs(n, no) {
  showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showDivs(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Multiple Slider</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/w3.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/side-menu.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="https://assets.pernod-ricard.com/nz/media_images/test.jpg?hUV74FvXQrWUBk1P2.fBvzoBUmjZ1wct" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/2183169552/the-test-fun-for-friends-logo.png" style="width:100%">
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
  
  </div>

  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="https://assets.pernod-ricard.com/nz/media_images/test.jpg?hUV74FvXQrWUBk1P2.fBvzoBUmjZ1wct" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/2183169552/the-test-fun-for-friends-logo.png" style="width:100%">
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 1)">&#10095;</button>
  
  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So i got your html, put the js in. Then i created from the two sliders my six. I changed on the buttons the `plusDivs` like u said - the first one with `1, 0` - second with `1, 1` - third with `1, 2` - fourth with `1, 3` - fifth with `1, 4` and the six one with `1, 5`. Also i changed the classses from the img from first slider to `mySlides1`, second with `mySlides2` until `mySlides6`. In the js i changed `showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);` to `showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);
showDivs(1, 2);
showDivs(1, 3);
showDivs(1, 4);
showDivs(1, 5);`

Comment: @just code
could you help in this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61043216/how-to-run-multiple-javascript-sliders-on-a-single-page

Answer (score 2):

Multi slide html content

```
<h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>

<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="q1.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="q2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="q3.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="q3.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="q2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="q1.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>


<p>Slideshow 3:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="q2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="q1.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="q3.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
</div>


<p>Slideshow 4:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides4">
    <img src="q1.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides4">
    <img src="q2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>



  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 3)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 3)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Script changes respect to multi slide index

```
<script>
var slideIndex = [1,1,1,1,1]; //.. multi slide index count

var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2","mySlides3","mySlides4","mySlides5"] // .. multi slide class  name in array


//initalization 
showSlides(1, 0);  // zero  index
showSlides(1, 1);  // first  
showSlides(1, 2);  // second  
showSlides(1, 3);  // third 
showSlides(1, 4);   //four 
//....

//handling  previous slide  
function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}


</script>
```

Try this code.