# How to run multiple JavaScript sliders on a single page?

Tags: javascript, slider

I am very new in JavaScript. I have multiple sliders on a single screen. You can see by going on this link: http://iliachtida.sportpolis.gr/play-unit/#

I am running a slider when click on the current product, but my slider behavior goes wrong when I click on the arrow.

When I click on the arrow only one product image is displayed, all the other images are not displayed.

I want to run different sliders for different products. Suppose I have four products on this screen and every product has four images. I want to run first product images on first product arrow click, second product images on second product arrow click, etc. I hope you understand.

I have tried many code, but it does not work for me.

This is my code:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("size-full");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) 
  {
      //alret(slideIndex);
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  /*for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }*/
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  //dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? do you want it to behave in a way that when one product is displayed on the left, the next one is displayed on the right?

Comment: Because currently the images rotates between the four sliders, so it's unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @MosiaThabo Thanks for your response. I want to run different slider for different product. I have four product on this screen every product has four images. I want to to run first product images on first product arrow click.
second product images on second product arrow click. I hope you understand.

Comment: Ok, So basically you want the product images to stop on the last image on each product instead of displaying nothing?

Comment: Please include HTML just for one product? I should be able to implement this quickly for you

Comment: Yes. html is coming dynamically in wordpress. you can check by inspect element.

Comment: Right now, clicks on different products are also controlling the slide effects on other products as well. So you have to find a way to seperate the sliders on code in the shortest way possible

Comment: @MosiaThabo that's the problem I am facing I want focused on current product slider.
When current product arrow clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210998/discussion-between-abhishek-bhardwaj-and-mosia-thabo).